# How to update just a specific view of listview item?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a **listview** that each items have a **progressbar** that update every seconds, so I used `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update each **item of list view**, in this state every things is OK, But I also have a **button** on this item of list view that has its `setOnClickListener` , as listview `notifyDataSetChanged()` is calling every second, this button clicking not working.

So, Can I update just that **ProgressBar**? not whole the **itemView**?

or any solution to solve this problem?

**CODE**

```
private fun createDownloadingItemView(video: Video): View {
    val view = UIHelper.createLayout(this@DownloadManagerPage, R.layout.layout_downloading_item)
    view.downloadProgressBar.progress = video.downloadProgress

    view.deleteFileImageView.setOnClickListener {
        showDeleteDialog(video)
    }

    return view
}
```

**Interface**

```
override fun onDownloadChanged(progressPercent: Int) {
    downloadFiles = Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<Video>>(
        ValueDB.downloadFiles,
        object : TypeToken<List<Video>>() {}.type
    )

    downloadingFiles.clear()
    downloadingFiles.addAll(downloadFiles.filter { downloadFile -> downloadFile.isDownloading })

    downloadingAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: Please post some code snippets

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous code added.

Comment: Are there any `view` modification calls off the UI/main thread? If so, you should perform those on UI thread, and it should be fine.